# HTTParty over-riding the native delete in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, httparty

I am trying to `delete` a record from the database through the controller as follows:

```
Model.where("property_1  = ? OR property_2 = ?", value_1, value_2).first.destroy
```

And I have a Rspec test for it as follow:

```
it "should do stuff" do
  expect{ post :create, @model_instance }.to change{ Model.count }.by -1
end
```

And this passes.

However, when I change my code to use `delete` in place of `destroy` as follow:

```
Model.where("property_1  = ? OR property_2 = ?", value_1, value_2).first.delete
```

The test failed with the following error:

```
ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
```

On careful examination, it turned out that I was including `HTTParty` in my model Class (`include HTTParty`) which has a delete method that is over-riding the native one:

```
def delete
  self.class.delete(id) if persisted?
  @destroyed = true
  freeze
end
```

So, my question is: does using `HTTParty` means that I won't be able to use the native `delete` method again? knowing that `delete` will remove the record without triggering any callback as `destroy` would. (I won't want to use `destroy` and then manually `skip_callbacks` when `delete` could do just that for me)

Thanks in advance for responses

Comment: Is that "should do stuff" test correct? Shouldn't it start `expect { delete :delete, @model_instance }`

Comment: @ReggieB thanks for that observation, and yes it is correct. I am doing the delete in a `before_action` for the `create` method of another resource.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to alias the delete method before you include HTTParty. Something like:

```
alias_method :model_delete, :delete
include HTTParty
```

Then:

```
model.delete # calls HTTParty's delete instance method
model.model_delete # call ActiveRecord delete instance method
```